# How to handle input events with express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm still trying to wrap my head around express so I apologize for what is probably a very obvious question.

I have two input forms, and I want to update each of them when I type in the other. Here is my index.pug

```
form(action='/', method='post')
    input(name='kms', type='number', placeholder='Kilometers', onkeyup='updateMiles')
    input(name='ms', type='text', placeholder='Miles', onkeyup='updateKilometers')
```

So when I type a number into the kilometers input, the miles input box should update automatically with every keypress. The problem is I don't know how to handle this 'onkeyup' event with express. I tried placing the function in index.js but it doesn't work.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
...
function updateMiles() {
  var input = document.forms[0].kms;
  document.forms[0].ms = input/1.609344;
}
...
module.exports = router;
```

I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: updateMiles is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup`

I cannot find any references on the proper way to handle this. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need express to do that? You can do conversion right there, on the "client" side. Express is for server-side JS. Maybe I've missed something?

Comment: You need to understand one thing that JavaScript can run on both sides yes, but you can't do DOM manipulation in back-end with JS, that's the job of client side JS.

Comment: You're both right, of course. I was just making it more complicated than I needed it to be. Thank you!